# Siebel Operation Error for Inserting Field based on picklist

Tags: siebel

I am facing an issue where I am getting the below error while inserting a record in the table via Siebel Operation step.

Here the error is showing for field which is based on a picklist. Could anyone please suggest why i am getting this error:

```
SBL-DAT-00225: The value entered in field District of buscomp Contact_Address_LT does not match any value in the bounded pick list PickList Comm Resolution.
SBL-BPR-00100: This error is returned when the workflow/task is executing the Siebel Operation business service.
```

I am aware that this happens when the value is not defined in the picklist. But i have verified this, and LOV is having the value which I am trying to get insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is quite common. And could happen for a couple of reason.
As you have mentioned, that you have already checked the value which is getting inserted is already there in the LOV defined for the picklist.

I have recently faced this error, and spent hours to debug it. Try below to sort your problem.

Check for the below points:

1) Check for the pick map for this field, check if any contraint field is also present in it.

2) If yes, then check those constraint field is also getting inserted in same Siebel Operation step. Siebel does not follow sequence in the input argument. So if this is the case do step 3 to resolve your issue.

3) Split the insert statement into 2 parts, 1 where you insert the record with the values which is present in the pick map constraint and then update the same record. This will ensure that all the required field are populated.

Comment: Yes, this field is having constraint on 2 other fields. I will ensure that they get populated first. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from 8.1.1.4 is to add parameter into OM's config file, e.g `fins.cfg`:

```
[Task]
ProcessArgAsc = true
```

More details in my oracle support.